# pyyaml parse data with tag

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have yaml data like the input below and i need output as key value pairs

Input

```
a="""
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
code:
- '716'
- '718'
id:
- 488
- 499
"""
```

ouput needed

```
{'code': ['716', '718'], 'id': [488, 499]}
```

The default constructor was giving me an error. I tried adding new constructor and now its not giving me error but i am not able to get key value pairs.
FYI, If i remove the `!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` line from my yaml then it gives me desired output.

```
def new_constructor(loader, tag_suffix, node):

     if type(node.value)=='list':
         val=''.join(node.value)
     else:
         val=node.value
     val=node.value
     ret_val="""
     {0}
     """.format(val)
     return ret_val

yaml.add_multi_constructor('', new_constructor)
yaml.load(a)

output

"\n     [(ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value=u'code'), SequenceNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', value=[ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value=u'716'), ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value=u'718')])), (ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value=u'id'), SequenceNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', value=[ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value=u'488'), ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value=u'499')]))]\n     "
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution using PyYAML, but I recommend using [`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) instead. If for no other reason, it's more actively maintained than PyYAML. A quote from the overview

> Many of the bugs filed against PyYAML, but that were never acted upon, have been fixed in `ruamel.yaml`

To load that string, you can do

```
import ruamel.yaml
parser = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

obj = parser.load(a)  # as defined above.
```

Comment: In order to be able to again dump `obj`, including the tag, `obj` is not a simple `dict` and the values are not simple `list`s. But they function as such, and if necessary you can do something like `{x: list(y) for x, y in obj.items()}`

Comment: Thanks , Andrew, Let me check it out.

Comment: One other thing to note: PyYAML was implemented to handle the YAML 1.1 specification, whereas `ruamel.yaml` was written to handle 1.2. I'm not certain, but it looks like that `--- !ruby/hash` line is a 1.2 feature, which may also be why PyYAML doesn't like it out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend following @Andrew F answer, but in case you
wonder why your code did not get the proper result, that is because
you don't correctly process the node under the tag in your tag
handling.

Although the node's value is a list (of tuples with key value pairs),
you should test for the type of the node itself (using `isinstance`)
and then hand it over to the "normal" mapping processing routine as
the tag is on a mapping:

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader

a = """\
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
code:
- '716'
- '718'
id:
- 488
- 499
"""

def new_constructor(loader, tag_suffix, node):
    if isinstance(node, yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
        return loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    raise NotImplementedError

yaml.add_multi_constructor('', new_constructor, Loader=SafeLoader)


data = yaml.load(a, Loader=SafeLoader)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'code': ['716', '718'], 'id': [488, 499]}
```

You should  not use PyYAML's `yaml.load()`, it is documented to be potentially unsafe
and above all it is not necessary. Just add the new constructor to the `SafeLoader`.

Comment: ok, Thanks Anthon. Let me try it out. Meanwhile i am also thinking of removing the tags from data using regex and then calling safeloader.